# How does SQL Server create data types for a new column and why decimal calculation might differ?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose that I have two similar tables, with `[Data]` being an existing column on both tables. I'm going to create two new columns by adding `0.000001` and `0.01` to it. So I'm creating the columns `[Data + 0.000001]` and `[Data + 0.01]`.

```
SELECT 
    [Data],
    [Data + 0.000001] = [Data] + 0.000001,
    [Data + 0.01] = [Data] + 0.01
FROM 
    TableOne
```

My expectation was that the result would be like this:

| Data | Data + 0.000001 | Data + 0.01 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25.00 | 25.000001 | 25.01 |
| 26.00 | 26.000001 | 26.01 |
| 0.00 | 0.000001 | 0.01 |

However, it didn't turn out like so. After some investigating, I noticed that on one table, the column `[Data]` is `Numeric (13,2)` and it behaves just like the table above. However, on the second table, the column `[Data]` is `Decimal (38,2)` and it seems to be rounding the number down to the two digits. So the result becomes like this:

| Data | Data + 0.000001 | Data + 0.01 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25.00 | 25.00 | 25.01 |
| 26.00 | 26.00 | 26.01 |
| 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.01 |

My guess is that SQL Server tries to 'preserve' the original data type, so it'll try to preserve `Decimal (38,2)` and `Numeric (13,2)` for the new columns. Since `Numeric (13,2)` is not the maximum precision, SQL Server allows the precision/scale to increase and 'correctly' calculate the `[Data + 0.000001]` column. However, since `Decimal (38,2)` is already at maximum, it does not do so and rounds the result.

So I have two questions:

1. Wondering whether that is correct and how does SQL Server (or other databases) manages new column datatypes?
2. How to ensure that this issue do not happen when calculating columns (what effort you put to ensure your columns/calculation behave as you intended) or perhaps could we set up SQL Server/SSMS to send a warning when these things happen/could happen?

Thank you!

Comment: I doesn't look to me like you are creating new columns. You are just writing a query. If you wanted a specific datatype in those results, you would need to specific the conversion in the query. In any case, any numeric column that has only two decimal places will never allow you to add .000001 and keep that precision.

Comment: For your first question, the [behaviour of precision and scale during  operations is documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).  The pertinent part for you is probably the footnote below the table - *"The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. When a result precision is greater than 38, it's reduced*" - since your original data type is (38.2), the resulting scale cannot go beyond 2 without a potential loss of data

Comment: For your second question, you should use explicit conversion rather than relying on implicit conversion ([Example on db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=32d045185f9e26f63ef4d5bbb883e4f3)). You need to convert your data first, then add `0.00001` otherwise the implicit conversion still happens first. If you try and convert to a type that is going to result in data loss you'll get an error message

Comment: Aside... while reading the [Precision, scale, and Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql) documentation that GarethD linked you can follow along and experiment with [sp_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql) to invoke your query and confirm the expected outcomes.

Comment: Ok, thank you all! @topsail , @GarethD , @AlwaysLearning So takeaway is that I should be more diligent in knowing the data types and do explicit conversions rather than depending on implicit conversions. I'll also try experiment with `sp_describe_first_result_set`